# How to fix "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../docs/assets/css/main.css'" when generating documentation?

Tags: angular, typescript, documentation, documentation-generation, typedoc

I am trying to use typedoc to automatically generate the documentation for an Angular application.

Whenever I run `npx typedoc --out docs app --exclude "**/*.{spec.ts}" --exclude node_modules --ignoreCompilerErrors`, it's generating Markdown files, and the rendering finishes. It then aborts with the error stated above, saying that `.../docs/assets/css/main.css` does not exist.

From my understanding, this `main.css` is part of the typedoc stack and should be moved to the assets folder upon running this command.

Am I misunderstanding this? What is the reason for the failure, and how can I fix this?

---

I have played a little bit with typedoc, and the problem only seems to appear with the "default" theme:

```
$ typedoc --out docs app --theme default
Loaded plugin /home/name/work/stuff/src/main/webapp/node_modules/typedoc-plantuml
Loaded plugin /home/name/work/stuff/src/main/webapp/node_modules/typedoc-plugin-markdown

Using TypeScript 3.8.3 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib
Rendering [========================================] 100%
fs.js:130
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/name/work/stuff/src/main/webapp/src/docs/assets/css/main.css'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:451:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:353:35)
    at Renderer.<anonymous> (/home/name/work/stuff/src/main/webapp/node_modules/typedoc-plantuml/lib/plugin.js:117:23)
    at triggerEvents (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/utils/events.js:128:43)
    at triggerApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/utils/events.js:110:13)
    at eventsApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/utils/events.js:21:18)
    at Renderer.trigger (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/utils/events.js:264:13)
    at Renderer.render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/output/renderer.js:39:18)
    at CliApplication.generateDocs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/application.js:100:23)
    at CliApplication.bootstrap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/cli.js:48:26) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/name/work/stuff/src/main/webapp/src/docs/assets/css/main.css'
}
```

`typedoc --out docs app --theme minimal` runs without problems.